# Unable to use spring.activemq.broker-url from yaml configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, yaml, spring-jms, broker

I'm trying to inject activemq properties from a yaml configuration file.

i initially used a property file, and it worked pretty well, but with the yaml file, the property spring.activemq.broker-url is apparently ignored by spring-jms, and the default broker url is used (tcp://localhost:61616) with as result a "Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry" of course.

here's my yaml configuration

```
spring: 
 activemq: 
  broker-url: tcp://someIP:61616
  user: admin
  password: admin
  pooled: true
```

The yaml file is loaded since other configuration properties were correctly detected, i don't know if there's any issue with using yaml to setup activemq configuration..

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: For the record, `spring-jms` has nothing to do with this. Spring Boot is actually processing that file. Stupid question: are you sure that this file is actually read? It should be named `application.yml` at the same location as the properties file was.

Comment: Yes i'm quite sure. As i said in the first thread, some other properties were set up on the same yaml file and loaded correctly, the only ones not working are those related to activemq

Comment: Are you sure you added the dependency (in you pom.xml if using maven): `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq`

Comment: also, if you enable connection pooling, you need to add another dependency: `org.messaginghub:pooled-jms` (to your pom.xml if you use maven); and the property is: `spring.activemq.pool.enabled=true`